# How to make a replacement belt for Ender 3 v2?

Tags: creality-ender-3, belt

I need to replace one of the belts on my Ender 3 v2. I have ordered the timing belt and crimp ends to make a new belt but I am wondering what is the best way to make a new belt.

I was thinking of making one end of the belt with the crimp end, slotting it in place then running it through the pulleys and pathway until it reaches the other slot. Of course, I would adjust the tensioner to able to tighten the belt. Once I have a taut length, I would cut the belt and add the second crimp end. Finally, reassemble everything and tension the belt accordingly.

Am I missing anything that I should do? Is there a better way to make a belt?

(I opened up one of the "crimps" and it looks to be a 7mm diameter tube that had the belt inserted into it. The crimp was flattened onto the belt then folded in half. The metal is harder than brass or copper. It took considerable effort to open up.)

These are the original belt ends.

[image]

Comment: There is usually a message printed on belts not to crimp them... Please provide a photo of the old situation (to understand what the old situation was) and the crimped version for people to comment on. I usually make sure the belt is perfectly aligned with the axis and it is clamped in (for a different printer, I usually use a [printed toothed attachment piece](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1433295)).

Comment: Those are standard crimps and the standard method creality uses. Brass also is known to *work harden*

Comment: You should just be able to print a belt endstop that slides on from the side and matches the belt tooth profile, if you have access to another printer.

Comment: I don't have access to another printer. But I will try and find, or make, endstops once I get my printer up and running.

Comment: actually... that is brass - brass hardens if bent and crimped.